# Request to own API endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

On the node/express side I'm trying to make an get request to an endpoint I just created.

What is the correct way to do this? Can I use the fetch library (isomorphic-fetch)

My attempt:

```
router.get('/displayweather', function(req, res) {  

  fetch('/weather')
    .then(function(response){
      res.send(response);
    });
});

router.get('/weather', function(req, res){
  var fetchUrl = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/xyz-token/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
  fetch(fetchUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad request response from server");
      }
      return response.text();

    }).then(function(body) {
      res.send(body);

    });

});
```

Where there is another router.get(..) method retrieving weather data using an external API

Comment: Try it and see if it works.

Comment: My attempt causes the page to hang

Comment: What is `/weather`? Is that another site with an API, or is that your own server? You appear to be mixing up server/client code.

Comment: It is on my server just a couple of lines below this one

Comment: Can you add that code to your question so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: It looks like you should have a 301 redirect there, not an internal proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd forget about that first part and concentrate on that code you added:

Server

```
router.get('/weather', function(req, res){
  var fetchUrl = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/xyz-token/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
  fetch(fetchUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad request response from server");
      }

      // return json
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(body) {

      // but stringify it when you send it
      res.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    });
});
```

Client

```
fetch('/weather')
  .then(function (json) {
    return JSON.parse(json);
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    // do something with the data
  })
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so it's not possible to do the equivalent on the backend? Or is it just bad practice and I should be using modules to replicate the functionality instead?

And also I can't get the example you gave to work due to my lack of understanding of how to deal with response objects..